# How can I evenly space icons in an Ubuntu panel?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, display

This is a silly, nitpicky little thing, but I have a laptop with a less-than-desirable amount of screen real estate, so it bothers me. I've added a bunch of application launchers to the default panel at the top of my screen (to the right of the Applications/Places/System menus.) The problem is, I can't seem to control the spacing of the icons - I have quite a bit of space available at the right of the panel, and I can drag each individual icon over, but it seems like each icon is attached to its neighbor to the right. So I move one over, and the next one comes with it. Then I move that one, and the one to it's left comes too. The end result is I have several clumps of very-closely-clustered icons, with a lot of space between each clump.

Is there any way to control the spacing automatically? Snap to grid, auto-space, anything? Because my screen is tiny and resolution is pretty high, each icon is very small, and when they're so close together I sometimes end up clicking the wrong one.

I'm running Lucid, and am open to installing things if there's a package that would give me more control over the presentation. I'm also relatively new to Linux, so maybe there's a setting I'm missing somewhere in one of the preferences menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a gnome applet in the repos called quick-lounge-applet that should do what you want. After you install it it should be in your gnome applets list as "Launchers List". You will have to move your applets section on the panel to whee you want it and add all your launchers to the applet but it is organized!

Comment: Thanks! That looks like what I'm looking for. I received an answer on another forum suggesting Docky, or AWN; I tried both but I'm not really interested in making my computer look like a Mac.